# converting class extension to java extension in netbeans

Tags: java, class, netbeans

While trying to build my project I've did something and entire .java files became .class files in netbeans. Now I can't change any code. Netbeans can not open the class files. How can I fix this?

Here is a screenshot in case I'm not clear enough:

[image] [image]

**FIXED**
This project was imported from the eclipse. I've imported it again and now it works. It seems instead of copying to its own workspace netbeans was direcly using it in the eclipse workspace. When I moved the folder out of the eclipse workspace it caused this problem. Now I've made it create a new copy in netbeans workspace.

Comment: Those are compiled classes. You don't need to edit them just make changes to your source and rebuild

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera They have replaced the source code for some reason(unless I am missing something)

Comment: click on the services tab, and then click the project tab. you are actually seeing the files tab; by some reason the projects tab seems to be selected.

Comment: @WVrock  yes. you missed something for sure. you may selecting target location instead of source.

Comment: @SQL.injection it didn't work. As you can see in the new image I've just added. Other project's files are java instead of class.

Comment: @WVrock now click on projects again.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera 's tip did the trick. This project was imported from the eclipse some time ago. I have imported again and now they work. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @WVrock Maybe you compiled your source code :-P